# DBContext throwing errors attaching unique objects, with nullable foreign keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Most posts around the ObjectStateManager are true-duplicate issues based on unique primary keys.  My problem is that my table does Not have a primary key, but it does have multiple foreign keys, one of which is Nullable.

```
class MyObject
{
    int   Key1;
    int?  Key2;
}


context.MyTable.Attach(new MyObject() { Key1 = 100; Key2 = null; });
context.MyTable.Attach(new MyObject() { Key1 = 100; Key2 = 2000; }); ****
```

It blows up on the second call, even though this is a unique row in the database.

Any thoughts on how to get around this?  or enforce checking of BOTH keys?

Comment: Is there any reason you want to avoid adding an Id property to serve as a primary key?

Comment: Good point, I'll bring that up in discussion.  It would make my life a lot easier.

Comment: Table with 2 FK and nothing else sounds like a mapping table for many-to-many relationship. Please consider making Key1 and Key2 a composite primary key in that case.

Comment: I had considered the composite primary key, but I thought anything that is Nullable cannot be used in a PK.  Composite or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

As @BenAaronson mentioned, you should have a surrogate, primary key in your table in this instance. Entity Framework quite simply cannot deal with entities that have no primary key defined—in fact, I'm surprised your code even compiled/ran. Perhaps your real code with real class and property names caused EF to infer a primary key using its default conventions. For example:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public int MyClassId { get; set; }
    public int MyOtherClassId { get; set; }
}
```

In the code above, even without explicitly declaring it, EF would assume that the `MyClassId` property is the primary key for the class `MyClass`, even if that may not have been your intention.

If EF can't infer a primary key and one is not explicitly provided, then your code wouldn't compile (or at most, it wouldn't run).

So looking at your code, what appears to be happening is that EF inferred a primary key somehow (in your example above, `Key1`). You then tried to attach a new object to your context:

```
context.MyTable.Attach(new MyObject() { Key1 = 100; Key2 = null; });
```

This results in the context adding a new `MyObject` instance whose primary key value is `100` and whose `Key2` property is `null`.

Next, you attempt to attach another item to the context:

```
context.MyTable.Attach(new MyObject() { Key1 = 100; Key2 = 2000; });
```

What this does is attempt to add a new item to the context whose primary key is `100`, and this fails. This is because you already have an object being tracked by the context whose primary key value is `100` (executed by the first statement above).

Since you need to allow possibly `null` values for the `Key2` property, you can't use a composite primary key, as you already stated. So you will need to follow @BenAaronson's advice and add a surrogate primary key:

```
public class Object
{
    // Alternatively, you can use a mapping class to define the primary key
    // I just wanted to make the example clear that this is the
    // surrogate primary key property.
    [Key]
    private int ObjectID { get; set; } // IIRC, you can make this private...
    public int Key1 { get; set; }
    public int Key2 { get; set; }
}
```

Now, you can do the following:

```
context.MyTable.Add(new MyObject() { Key1 = 100, Key2 = null; });
context.MyTable.Add(new MyObject() { Key1 = 100, Key2 = 2000; });
```

Notice I used the `Add` method and not `Attach`. That's because when using `Attach`, the context is assuming that you're adding an object to the context which already exists in the database, but which was not brought into the context via a query; instead, you had a representation of it in memory, and at this point, you want the context to start tracking changes made to it and update the object in the database when you call `context.SaveChanges()`. When using the `Attach` property, the context adds the object in the `Unmodified` state. That's not what we want. We have brand new objects being added to the context. So we use `Add`. This tells the context to add the item in the `Added` state. You can make any changes you want to it. Since it's a new item, it will be in the `Added` state until you call `context.SaveChanges()` and the item is persisted to your data store, at which time, it's state will be updated to `Unmodified`.

One more thing to note at this point. If this is a "many-to-many" table, you should never need to manually add rows to this type of join table in EF (there are some caveats to this statement, see below). Instead, you should setup a mapping between the two objects whose relationship is many-to-many. It's possible to specify an optional many-to-many relationship, too. If the first object has no relationship to the second, there should be no row in the join table for the first object, and vice versa.

Regarding join table caveats as alluded to above: if your join-tables (i.e. many-to-many mapping tables) are simple (meaning the only columns in the table are those columns mapping one ID to the related ID), then you won't even see the join-table as part of your object model. This table is managed by EF in the background through navigation properties on the related objects. However, if the join-table contains properties other than just the ID properties of the related objects (and, this implies you have an existing database or explicitly structured your object model this way), then you will have an intermediate entity reference. For example:

```
public class A
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class AToB
{
    // Composite primary key
    [Key]
    public int IdA { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int IdB { get; set; }

    public A SideA { get; set; }
    public B SideB { get; set; }

    // An additional property in the many-to-many join table
    public DateTime Created {  get; set; }
}
```

You would also have some mappings to tell EF how to wire up the foreign key relationships. What you'd wind up with in your object model then, is the following:

```
myA.AToB.SideB  // Accesses the related B item to this A item.
myA.AToB.Created // Accesses the created property of AToB, telling you
                 // when the relationship between A and B was created.
```

In fact, if you have non-trivial join tables such as this example, EF will always include them in your object model when generating its model from an existing database.

I would strongly suggest that you check out Julie Lerman's and Rowan Miller's books on programming Entity Framework.